# Derive the formula of a function with a given properties.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have problem with formula derivation of function $f$, such that

$$f(0)=1\quad \wedge\quad\forall x\neq0:(x+1)f(x)=1-f(\frac1x)                               $$

My attempts:

1.For $x=-1$ we have:
$0=1-f(-1)$

2.So $f(-1)=f(0)=1$

Luckily I have answer to that problem, but I don't know process.

Ans: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

For $ x\ne 0$, we have

$$(x+1)f(x)=1-f(\frac 1x)$$

now replace $ x $ by $\frac 1x$, to get

$$(\frac 1x +1)f(\frac 1x)=1-f(x)$$

thus

$$(\frac 1x +1)\Bigl(1-(x+1)f(x)\Bigr)=1-f(x)$$

or
$$(x+1)-(x+1)^2f(x)=x(1-f(x))$$
hence

$$1=(x^2+x+1)f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Argument $\dfrac 1x$ has a clue:

Given
$$(x+1)f(x)=1-f(1/x)\tag1$$

Substitute $1/x$ in place of $x$

$$(\frac 1x +1)f(1/x)=1-f(x) \tag2$$

Eliminate $f(1/x)$ from 1) and 2) and algebraically simplify... to get the required result.